# DHCPv6 address xxxx/128 timeout preferred 140 valid 450

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipv6

A couple of days ago, I activated the IPv6 for an EC2 instance. But, yesterday the instance was down twice.

When checking the syslog file, I found these repeated message:

```
ens5: DHCPv6 address xxxx/128 timeout preferred 140 valid 450
```

And while doing some research, I found this [post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUX8AY0c-YSCWa2QdFgAS74Q), which simply says, the message is normal, but my question is is it?

Also, does it have anything to do with the server being down? I'm asking this because before I activated the IPv6, the instance had never been down, not even once.

I have a bit of network expertise, so any kind of clue on how to solve this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly normal. It informs you that an [ephemeral address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941#section-3.4) is valid for 450 seconds, but will not be used for outgoing traffic after 140 seconds.